# Animated widget pushes other widgets

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have an animated widget (image) located top of the page and under the widget there should be a text.

I use size transition widget and it pushes all the widgets under itself. I don't want my animation to push any other widgets. Everything should stay where they are. I expect something like this:

[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEClu.png)

```
Widget _animation() {
  Image img= Image.asset(
    'assets/images/myImg.jpg',
  );

  _controller.forward(from: 0);

  return SizeTransition(
    child: img,
    sizeFactor: CurvedAnimation(
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      parent: _controller,
    ),
  );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
    body: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      _animation(),
      Text(
        "My Text",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 30),
      ),
    ],
  ),
 ),
);
}
```

Comment: then, why are you using SizeTransition ? what effect do you need?

Comment: I need that curve effect can I use another animation widget for it?

Comment: how do you want to move the widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the SizeTransition won't work if you have given it's parent a fixed size. I am showing you how to do it using `Stack`.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(left: 0, child: _animation()),
          Positioned(top: 100, child: Text("This is your text",)),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: This is something that I exactly want and I tried it before. With this way it's not running the animation.

Comment: Actually the `SizeTransition` won't work if you have given it's parent a fixed size. So, you can either use `SlideTransition` or `Stack`, former is provided by a user already, if you want me to provide you `Stack` implementation I can do it.

Comment: OK, I have edited the solution, give this a try now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Stack and Positioned element, so that your element will clip above the elements that you're "moving". Think of it as a `position: absolute` in html.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SlideTransition` instead of `SizeTransition` because you want to move your image from top to real position.

```
  Widget _animation() {
    Image img= Image.asset(
    'assets/images/myImg.jpg',
    );
    _controller.forward(from: 0);
    return SlideTransition(
      child: img,
      position: Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0.0, -1.0), end: Offset.zero)
          .animate(_controller),  
    );
  }
```

More info here:

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SlideTransition-class.html